# Probability density function for a PDE with random inputs

Tags: probability-distributions, partial-differential-equations

I am looking for a general method or alternatively few textbook examples of deriving a probability density function for a solution of partial differential equation with random inputs in the equation and/or initial condition.

As an example problem I have in mind consider simple linear advection in a periodic domain and sin function as an initial condition:

\begin{gather}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + a \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 0
\\
u(x, 0) = \sin(x) + b
\\
u(0, t) = u(2\pi, t)
\end{gather}
where $a$ and $b$ can be either or both random variables with known distribution. I would like derive a PDF for the solution $u$ i.e.
\begin{gather}
p(v, x, t)\, \textrm{d}v = P(u(x,t) \in [v, v+\textrm{d}v)) 
\end{gather}
Is there a textbook on problems like this? I am searching the literature but encounter information about stochastic processes and stochastic differential equations. Stochastic partial differential equations look close to what I am looking for although in my case the random terms are not a function of time. A realization of the random variables in the above equations gives a deterministic problem.

Answer (score 1):

After looking through some fluid mechanics textbooks I found a similar problem and it seems that this can be solved by adopting a certain type of PDF and performing a little calculus involving Dirac's delta.

## PDF definition

Firstly, we assume we assume that the deterministic version of our problem has a solution:

\begin{equation}
u(x,t, \omega) = U(x, t, a(\omega), b(\omega)).
\end{equation}

Then we define the PDF as
\begin{equation}
p(u, b, x, t) = \int \int \! \delta(u - U(A, B, x, t)) \delta(a - A) q(A, B) \, \textrm{d}A \textrm{d}B
\end{equation}
where $q$ is the joint PDF for initial realization of variables $a$ and $b$.
This is referred to as *response-excitation* PDF or *fine-grained* PDF.

## Useful properties of Dirac's delta

Now we need to recall some Dirac's delta properties. These properties can be derived more formally by considering sequence of approximations to Dirac's delta functions.
\begin{gather}
\int \! \delta(x - a) f(x) \, \textrm{d}x = f(a)
\\
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \! \delta'(x - a) f(x) \, \textrm{d}x = \delta(x-a)f(x)\bigg|_{-\infty}^{\infty} -\int \! \delta(x-a) f'(x) \, \textrm{d} x =-f'(a)
\\
\int \! \delta(x - a) f(x)g(x) \, \textrm{d}x = f(a)g(a) = f(a) \int \! \delta(x - a) g(x) \, \textrm{d}x
\end{gather}
The first one is called a sifting property and the remaining ones are obtained via integration by parts and the sifting property. We can see from the latter two equations that Dirac's derivative is anti-symmetric i.e. we could write symbolically $\delta'(x-a) = -\delta(a - x)$.

## Derivation of the PDF transport equation

We first take the time derivative of the PDF
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int \! \delta(u - U(A, B, x, t)) \delta(b - B) q(A, B)\, \textrm{d} A \textrm{d} B = \ldots
\end{equation}

We assume that integral and differential operator commute and carry on using the chain rule:
\begin{equation}
\ldots = - \int \! \frac{\partial}{\partial u}\delta(u - U(A, B, x, t)) \frac{\partial U}{\partial t} \delta(a - A) q(A, B)\, \textrm{d} A \textrm{d} B 
\end{equation}
and again we commute the operators and observe that none of the other functions depend on $a$
\begin{equation}
\ldots = -\frac{\partial}{\partial u} \int \! \delta(u - U(A, B, x, t)) \frac{\partial U}{\partial t} \delta(a - A) q(A, B)\, \textrm{d} A \textrm{d} B 
\end{equation}
In order to reproduce the convective term we take the following expression
\begin{equation}
a \frac{\partial p}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\int \! A \delta(u - U(A, B, x, t)) \delta(a - A) q(A, B)\, \textrm{d} A \textrm{d} B = \ldots
\end{equation}
The first equality come from sifting property applied to product of functions. Then we apply identical trick:
\begin{equation}
\ldots = -\frac{\partial}{\partial u} \int \! \delta(u - U(A, B, x, t)) A \frac{\partial U}{\partial x} \delta(a - A) q(A, B)\, \textrm{d} A \textrm{d} B
\end{equation}

We can now add both expresions and use the original equation:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial U}{\partial t} + A  \frac{\partial U}{\partial x}=0
\end{equation}
So this example is pretty trivial as it leads to
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} + a  \frac{\partial p}{\partial x}=0
\end{equation}
Remembering thought that $p$ is a function of $u$, $a$ and time-space. $a$ random variable has not been removed from the formulation. It can be removed in the process of obtaining marginalised PDF for $u$ only. Integrating that equation over $a$ would give:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial p_u}{\partial t} + \mathbb E(A|u) \frac{\partial p_u}{\partial x}= 0
\end{equation}

## Burgers' equation (a different example)

A slightly more involved example would have a non-zero right-hand side in the original transport equations and a nonlinear advection. Burgers' equation fits these two criteria:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + u \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}  = \nu \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + f(x,t,b)
\end{equation}

The derivation is very similar and will result in the RHS in the PDF equation being a minus derivative of RHS of the original equation.

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} 
+ \int_{\infty}^a \frac{\partial p}{\partial x} \, \textrm{d}a' 
+ a \frac{\partial p}{\partial x} 
=
-f(x,t,b) \frac{\partial p}{\partial a} - \frac{\partial}{\partial a} 
\left\langle \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} \delta(a - u(x,t))\right\rangle
\end{equation}
where $a$ now takes the role of random variable representing the solution. I am still not completely sure why we need an additional integral term on the LHS.